# Which files suitable for code review in Angular 10 project

Tags: angular

I developed project using `Angular 10`. According to client request I need to send Angular source code for code review purpose. I can send source code to client. but my question is , do I need send `production files` (`dist` folder) to code review.

Angular 10 code review files

Comment: do you have existing CI/CD pipeline that you use? Which tool are you going to use for code review ?

Comment: it will do by client

Comment: Please help me understand your needs. If client is doing code review `manually` then he will need to have access to your code repo. In that case he will have to go through all your files not just `dist` folder. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: dist folder is not necessary for code review ?

Comment: `dist` folder is only required for deployment. Code review is always done on your actual code files